# Getting the rownumbers for all NA values of a column

Tags: r, na, grepl

I have data as follows:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,NA,4,5))
names(df)[1] <- "first_column"

  first_column
1            1
2            2
3           NA
4            4
5            5
```

I would like to get all the row numbers for which `first_column` is `NA`, so `3`

I found ways to look up other values, i.e. `which(grepl(2, df$first_column))`
but not `NA`. Including `NA` values is apparently quite cumbersome ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883598/grep-include-na-values-in-results)).
Is there an easier way to do this?

Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for `is.na`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `which` with `is.na`

```
which(is.na(df))
```

```
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
which(is.na(df$first_column)==T)
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

With a `tidyverse` approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,NA,4,5))
names(df)[1] <- "first_column"

df %>% 
  mutate(second_column = ifelse(is.na(first_column), row_number(), NA))

#>   first_column second_column
#> 1            1            NA
#> 2            2            NA
#> 3           NA             3
#> 4            4            NA
#> 5            5            NA
```